# Using JavaScript in a jQuery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I can't get it to work. How do I add JavaScript to a jQuery template?

I tried it in the following way without success:

```
<script id="geoShapeTooltip" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    ${ alert ("TEXT"); }
    <table id="tooltipTable" >
        <tr><th class="tooltipHeading" colspan="2">
                ${item.fieldValues.NAME}, ${item.fieldValues.REGION}</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Population:</td>
            <td>${item.fieldValues.POP2005}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

Here is my problem on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5ys9/1/).

edit: I found a different solution. In Infragistics templates you can execute javascript in if statements.
    {{if YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_GOES_HERE}}Some Text}}{{/if}}
And if you want, you can add values to the parameter, to display them later. A little bit hacky, but works.

Comment: @Thauwa http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates = valid

Comment: You need to find the JavaScript callback function for the tooltip hover/click event (if there is one). Start by looking at the igMap documentation.

Comment: It's an asp.net control, but the part i posted is jQuery. And as you see, i tried it like in the article, which doesn't work. It just shows ${ alert ("TEXT"); } as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried inserting a nested normal JavaScript tag inside of the jQuery templating script area and it seemed to work fine:

```
<script id="geoShapeTooltip" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <table id="tooltipTable" >
            <tr><th class="tooltipHeading" colspan="2">
                    ${item.fieldValues.NAME}, ${item.fieldValues.REGION}</th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Population:</td>
                <td>${item.fieldValues.POP2005}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('${item.fieldValues.NAME}');
    </script>
</script>
```

Obviously this has the disadvantage that you are effectively adding a new `<script type="text/javascript">..</script>` tag to the DOM each time a country is hovered over. The alternative and proper way to do it is to find out what event is triggered in the igMap documentation when a country/area is hovered over and write an event handler in your document.ready handler to listen for that event. If you do it this way, you need to use jQuery's `on` delegated event handler to listen for any events related to a particular class (i.e. `geoShapeTooltip`) as and when they are added dynamically to the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/W5ys9/6/

Comment: Good suggestion with the inline script tag. After a while i found an other way. seriesMouseLeftButtonUp works on the igMap. Even if it is not documented anywhere -.-